# How to get a value from Scale/Slider which generates a button in Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a button that when clicked displays slider / scale. How to get the selected value from slider?
My code returns error: "TypeError: funcSlider() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'"

```
self.list = {}

    def onClick(self):
        print (self.list)
        return
    def funcSlider(self, posX,posY,key,value):
        w = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=8, orient='horizontal')
        w.pack()
        w.place(x=posX, y=posY, in_=self)
        self.list [key] = value

button = tk.Button(self, text="button ",
                   command=lambda: self.funcSlider(120,33,'test'),width = 20)
button .pack(anchor="w")
button .place(x=250, y=50, in_=self)

button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Send",
                        command=self.onClick, width=42,bg="#4BAD2E")
button2 .pack(anchor="w")
button2 .place(x=250, y=430, in_=self)
```

Comment: where is the code of the function `funcSlider()`? it seems it takes 4 arguments, you have given it 3

Comment: @Begueradj I'm sorry, I made a typo :( I've already corrected code

Comment: note: there's no need to call `w.pack()` if you later call `w.place()`. You can only use one geometry manager for any given widget, and the last one you use is the one that has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it. I do not know if it is a 'good practice', but it works :D

```
self.list = {}

    def foo(self,x,key):
        self.list [key] = x
    def onClick(self):
        print (self.list)
        return
    def funcSlider(self, posX,posY,key):
        w = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=8, orient='horizontal',command=lambda s: self.foo(s,key))
        w.pack()
        w.place(x=posX, y=posY, in_=self)
        self.list [key] = value

button = tk.Button(self, text="button ",
                   command=lambda: self.funcSlider(120,33,'test'),width = 20)
button .pack(anchor="w")
button .place(x=250, y=50, in_=self)

button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Send",
                        command=self.onClick, width=42,bg="#4BAD2E")
button2 .pack(anchor="w")
button2 .place(x=250, y=430, in_=self)
```